# PHPBrew - Install php 5.3.2 with openSSL on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, openssl, phpbrew

I am trying to install PHP 5.3.2 on Ubuntu 18.04 using PHPBrew. I have no trouble with installing it without OpenSSL but when I want to install OpenSSL I get several errors.

My first attempt was to just use +openssl but then I got a lot of errors from OpenSSL. Then I installed OpenSSL 0.9.8 and used it as `+openssl=/usr/local/openssl/` and now I get the following error:

`configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's libraries`

I have no idea what libraries it can't find. I already fixed the missing `evp.h` file by making a symbolic link in `/usr/local/openssl` to `/usr/local/openssl/include/openssl/evp.h`.

**Edit:** Haven't found a fix yet, just went with the version without OpenSSL.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're trying to install such an old PHP version on 18.04?

Comment: All our applications are running on php 7.2 but one of our websites is running on Joomla 1.3 or something. It only runs on php 5.3. We want to get rid of our old server cluster where that site was running so I set up an Amazon EC2 instance where I want to install php 5.3 so we still can run that site. I know it's not secure but it doesn't matter for that site/server.